# Calculate distinguishable color palette in R

Tags: r, matlab, colors

I am using R to create a plot that contains 20 distinct groups, and I would like to color each of them differently.  I am also familiar with Matlab and when working with that program I have found that "distinguishable_colors" matlab file worked best for distinguishing different colors [1](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29702-generate-maximally-perceptually-distinct-colors).  I have looked at the "rainbow", "rainbow_hcl", and "brewer" palettes, but none of them look as good as "distinguishable_colors.mat".  I am wondering if anyone knows of a function in R that will create the same palette as the "distinguishable_colors.mat" matlab function?

Comment: Use a tool to find the colors that distinguishable_colors.mat gives and then program those into R?

Comment: Source code here, BSD licence http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29702-generate-maximally-perceptually-distinct-colors convert to R?

Answer (score 1):

That function in MatLab seems to iteratively search over RBG space for sets of color which are maximally different from each other. I don't know of such a thing in R, but we can come pretty close.

We can find a color palette of a few colors which suits our needs (perhaps using http://colorbrewer2.org/) and use those seed color to create a `colorRampPalette` for any number of colors.

```
pal<-colorRampPalette(c('#e41a1c','#377eb8','#4daf4a','#984ea3','#ff7f00'))
N=10
plot(rnorm(N),rnorm(N),pch=16,col=pal(N),cex=3)
```

Comment: `for( N in 2^( 2:13 ) ){ print( plot(rnorm(N),rnorm(N),pch=16,col=pal(N),cex=3) ) ; readline() }`

Answer (score 0):

The R package [`Polychrome`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=Polychrome) provides tools for qualitative palettes with many (20 or more) colors. It comes with two vignettes giving the [provided palettes](https://CRAN.R-project.org/web/packages/Polychrome/vignettes/polychrome.html) and tools for [creating palettes](https://CRAN.R-project.org/web/packages/Polychrome/vignettes/creatingPalettes.html).